# await is a reserved word error in Expo XDE for React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Right to the point:

I'm using Expo XDE with react-native to build a cross-platform mobile app.

I want to save and retrieve a couple of variables using AsyncStorage ("localstorage" alternative in react-native).

After adding the pieces of code to store and retrieve,

[image]

Expo XDE is showing the following error when building the JavaScript bundle: *"await is a reserved word"*

[image]

According to the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html), I got to use "await" when accessing AsyncStorage.

Any ideas? Is it a problem related to Expo XDE only?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use `await`, your function including `const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem();` needs to be async.

You can do like this :

```
async myfunction() {
  ...
  const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem();
  ...
}
```